# Overflow on a table with unknown width

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I'm having a problem with this code:

**CSS:**

```
        #pageBound{
            float:left;
            position:relative;
            left: 50%;
        }
        #page{
            float:left;
            position:relative;
            right: 50%;
        }
        .scroll{
            height: 150px;
            overflow-y: auto;
        }
        .myTable{
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        .myTable td{
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 10px 5px;
        }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id='pageBound'>
    <div id='page'>
        <div class='scroll'>
            <table class='myTable'>
                <tr><td>25.08.12 22:32:59</td></tr>
                <tr><td>25.08.12 22:32:59</td></tr>
                <tr><td>25.08.12 22:32:59</td></tr>
                <tr><td>25.08.12 22:32:59</td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Working example here: http://honzabrabec.cz/test/overflow.html

In all browsers except Opera it shrinks the table a bit (appends the scrollbar to the inside) and therefore the lines in the table break. Adding another wrapper around the table with padding doesn't solve the problem. However, if I change the 'overflow-y:auto' to 'overflow-y:scroll' it works fine in all browsers except IE. The same fix even works if I  add another table with 'overflow-y:scroll' to this page.

I want it to behave the same way as it behaves in Opera now. That means the table wont shrink. In other words I need the table to display the same way as if the overflow div was not present.

Comment: You're explaining what the problems are but not what you **want**.

Comment: Ok, I've added a sentence to the end :)

Comment: Are you amenable to JavaScript being used in the solution?

Comment: Preferably not. Actually I've solved it using javascript, but it seems hacky to me and I would like to avoid it if there is a better way

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
.myTable{
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

But then it appears an horizontal scrollbar.

Then, you can add

```
.myTable{
white-space: nowrap;
margin-right: 17px;/* or more */
}
```

It works on Firefox, but maybe there's a browser which has scrollbars of 30px...

Comment: I've thought about this, but that doesn't solve the cause. Basically I need the table to display the same way as if the overflow div was not present. That's because I don't even know the number of columns this table will have and sometimes the wrap will be just fine. I will state this in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace

```
.scroll {
    height: 150px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

with

```
.scroll {
    height: 150px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

But the problem is that if the table's height can be less than 150px, there will be a scrollbar too, even if it isn't necessary.

**Edit:**

Sorry, you knew it already.

But I would choose this solution which works on compliant browsers.

And for the users who use IE, you could try a javascript solution: http://remysharp.com/2008/01/21/fixing-ie-overflow-problem/